# What is the connotation of “The Hitchhiker's Guide to XYZ”?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

I am a software engineer, I have read some book/articles with the title "The Hitchhiker's Guide to XYZ", e.g. "[The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python](https://docs.python-guide.org/)" or "[The Hitchhiker's Guide to GitHub](https://dzone.com/articles/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-github-13-java-projects-y)" or "[Hitchhikers Guide To Modern Enterprise JavaScript](https://www.redhat.com/files/summit/session-assets/2017/S109244-balunas-summit17-hitchhikers-guide-to-nodejs.pdf)" (just to show a few examples)

I guess the titles are a reference to [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy). I don't read the book but I watched [the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(film)). I guess it is because of the culture difference and I am not a native speaker I didn't appreciate the movie. To me it is just a "bizarre" movie.

But what is the connotation of “The Hitchhiker's Guide to XYZ” ?

Comment: The snowclones are used (1) as snappy, hip titles (2) which will appeal to various types of people. They connote (a) an easy-going attitude to everything, (b) minimal cost / effort  involved, while (c) remaining interesting, informative, useful.

Comment: Do you know what a hitchhiker is? That should be your first point of research.

Comment: @StuartF Yes I know what a hitchhiker is. But that only adds to my confusion!

Comment: In English, we often take names of well-known books and adopt them to our own "thing".

Comment: As jsw29 suggests in a comment beneath DJClayworth's answer, framing a software programming manual as "A Hitchhiker's Guide to X" is an invocation of "programmer cool"—because the ironic, irreverent, playfully dark tone of Douglas Adams's book struck a chord with many techie people. In the U.S., what might be called a "hipster nerd" attitude among some computer hardware and software experts—based on their highly advanced technical competence and a skeptical or pessimistic worldview—emerged long ago. It is reflected in the ethos of _Dilbert_ (whom you know) and _The Hacker's Dictionary_.

Comment: It's not supposed to be meaningful, just "catchy".

Comment: I would recommend reading the book if you can. Not only is it _much_ much better than the movie in my opinion, but I think it may give you a better sense of the implied meaning of a "Hitchhiker's Guide" title.

Comment: @DavidZ: Highly agree on that.  Or listen to the radio play.  Or the audio-book recording, read by the author himself.  (Good performance of many of the character voices, and perfect performance of the sentence structure and so on, since of course he knows where each sentence is going and where to put the emphasis and pauses.)  The movie captured some of the story, but the tone was quite different from the book; I think it's widely agreed that the movie version isn't even trying to appeal to its audience in the same way as the book.

Comment: @PeterCordes I will try audio-book recording. I didn't get the movie at all.

Comment: The movie wasn't very memorable so I don't even remember if it would have made sense without knowing the book.  A lot of what's great about the book is the clever / funny wording the narration uses to describe things (which in the movie would be purely visual), and the descriptions of how the world works, not just what the characters are doing.  Things that don't really translate at all easily to a movie. (There was a TV show version of H2G2, though, which does manage some of the charm.  It's at least trying to be like the book. I'd recommend the book first (or instead), especially audiobook.)

Comment: For an example of the kind of narrator observations about society, [What does the initial fragment of The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/127608) quotes one of the first few paragraphs from the book.  That's the kind of insightful humour many of us love about H2G2.  Anyway, yeah, the audio book is an excellent place to start.  If you like it a lot, the BBC radio play was actually written and produced *first*, before the book, and has some story differences.  It's also very good, and it's interesting to compare the plot differences as well as style.

Comment: It appeals to those who are part of the cult - techies, avid sci-fi readers, etc

Comment: @DavidZ They should read all five volumes of the trilogy ;-). Especially because in the last volume a late, multidimensional iteration of the hitchhiker's guide is introduced whose first action is to calibrate to the current reader's spectrum of senses... *"Can you hear me when I say this?" "When you say what?" "Good", said the bird.* That's what good manual writers aspire to, right?

Comment: @PeterCordes I remember reading Douglas Adams said that there wasn't really one "definitive" HHGTTG. The radio play is purposefully different from the book, and when he was writing the movie he intentionally deviated from the book series. So every media HHGTTG exists in, it's always different.  That viewpoint helped me appreciate the movie more, than when I thought it was "Hollywood" changing the story.

Answer (score 67):

*The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* is itself a reference to a book title that was well-known at the time Douglas Adams wrote his original radio drama.

"[The Hitchhiker's Guide to Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitch-hiker%27s_Guide_to_Europe)" by Ken Welsh, published in 1971, was a well known title at the time. The book is exactly what it says - a guide to traveling in Europe for those on a cheap budget, which in those days often involved actual hitchhiking. It has a "hip", informal and irreverent vibe that readers of Adams' work will recognize. The connection to HHGG is well documented.

The book focused on practical advice rather than cultural or historical description, it took an informal style, and was intended for those wanting to get maximum value for little outlay and who are prepared to "rough it".  It is these aspects that the more recent titles are probably intended to evoke.

Comment: So the point of those titles are "practical advices" ?

Comment: To avoid confusing the OP still more, it should probably be added that the titles of this form, in their present use, are intended more to evoke a certain attitude, a certain frame of mind (which is associated both with actual hitchhiking and with appreciation of *The Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy*), than to convey any definite information.

Comment: I very much doubt that modern usages of this title format are in any way intended to, or generally interpreted to, (directly) reference *The Hitchhiker's Guide to Europe*, or the style contained therein, as this answer seems to imply. I would assume most/all such titles are mostly/exclusively referencing *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*, given that this is far more prevalent in modern discourse (especially in the programming community).

Comment: @NotThatGuy I don't think the answer is implying that the recent titles are directly referencing _Hitchhiker's Guide to Europe_, but rather it's explaining how the title _Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy_ came to be in the first place and what it was supposed to mean (which was indeed a reference to _Hitchhiker's Guide to Europe_.) Without that context, the title of HHGG doesn't make much sense (either to me or apparently to the OP) and the context that comes with the title is lost.

Comment: @reirab I didn't read the question as asking where the title of *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* came from (although I suppose it could be asking that). But that question would be off topic. I rather read it as asking why everyone is using the "The Hitchhiker's Guide to XYZ" title format, which seems to have everything to do with HHGG and not all that much to do with whatever that's based on (and with that interpretation of the question, the answer is very much saying those titles are directly based on *The Hitchhiker's Guide to Europe*).

Comment: @NotThatGuy The question explicitly asks for the connotation of "Hitchhiker's Guide to XYZ." Without explaining why HHGG chose that title and what it intended to mean by it, much of that connotation is lost, IMO.

Comment: @reirab Whatever context you think would or would not be useful doesn't change the fact that it's (presumably) *objectively wrong* to imply that recent "The Hitchhiker's Guide to XYZ" titles are a reference to *The Hitchhiker's Guide to Europe*, and that's very much the message I'm getting from this answer. If you try to remove your bias of already knowing the answer to the question, and you instead read exactly what's written, you may see that too.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I didn't already know that prior to reading this answer. I still found it to be useful context in explaining what the title means.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your discussion. To me all those information is a "nice to know" fact. BTW, my question is indeed "asking why everyone is using the "The Hitchhiker's Guide to XYZ" title format".

Answer (score 8):

The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* that we read, hear, or even watch is funny, and fun.  "Don't Panic" is a key theme, certainly.  But within what we see, the Guide is a book (an electronic or equivalent one).  That, within the universe of the stories, is successful for three reasons, compared to the Encylopedia Galactica:

- the text "Don't Panic" on the cover
- the price

(these two are clearly stated together) and,

- the reassuring tone (Earth is described as "Mostly Harmless" in later editions, which also demonstrates that it doesn't try to give all the tedious details).

Done well, a programming book inspired by the Hitchhiker's Guide should be a light-hearted, informal overview, probably with some entertaining asides and examples.  It's not meant to be a complete language reference listing every possible permutation of parameters, which would be a weighty and pricey tome.

The target market for such a guide would appear to be those with an understanding of programming who are new to the specific subject, and can immediately benefit from something quickly readable.

*I'm most familiar with it in book form, which was adapted from the original radio series by the same author, and is a pretty faithful re-rendering of the same material in a different format.

Comment: This is to make my comments (and some subsequent discussion) into a more permanent and organised form, filled out with what would have been several more comments

Comment: The python book does say this in introduction section "The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python exists to provide both novice and expert Python developers a best practice handbook for the installation, configuration, and usage of Python on a daily basis."    https://docs.python-guide.org/intro/duction/

Answer (score 7):

### ***Don't Panic***

This is inscribed on the actual ([in-universe meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in-universe)) cover of the [Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Panic:_The_Official_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_Companion)

It means to take a relaxed attitude towards new and interesting situations, and learn from everything, no matter how absurd it appears to be. That's all.

---

EDIT

No, this is not a joke. It expresses quite succinctly the attitude and blithe spirit of the rest of the book.

Those who have seen only the movie and not read the book are probably not going to understand the reference...
[image]

Comment: What's with the link to a companion book? I think you meant to link [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (fictional)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(fictional)), since the IRL HHG2G doesn't necessarily have "Don't Panic" on the cover (e.g. [the first edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:H2G2_UK_front_cover.jpg)).

Comment: @wjandrea: the actual Guide _as described in the book_ did have "Don't Panic" on the cover, in big reassuring letters.

Comment: Some editions did have "DON'T PANIC" on the cover.  Mine does, and it's not the one pictured [here](https://www.panmacmillan.com/blogs/science-fiction-and-fantasy/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy-cover-design) with the customisable stickers for the cover (or my stickers were missing)

Comment: But as well as the "don't panic" message, the tone of such a book should be light-hearted and informal, rather than dwelling on tedious details.  In the case of programming books it's the antithesis of a language reference

Comment: @Remco Yes, that's what I'm saying: the fictional book has "Don't Panic" on the cover, not the IRL book

Comment: I don't get how this is supposed to answer OP's question, is this a joke answer?

Comment: No, this is not a joke. It expresses quite succinctly the attitude and  blithe spirit of the rest of the book. Perhaps you are not familiar with the original?

Comment: That last comment should be in your actual answer.  Remember, people wanting to know the answer to this question likely aren't familiar with H2G2, or didn't "get it" if they are.  Besides that, I don't think your current answer does a very good job of explaining what about the H2G2 attitude is really relevant.  I know what you mean by "relaxed attitude" because I do know the H2G2 books, but @Chris H's comment looks to me like a much better explanation.  This answer in its current form seems... mostly harmless.

Comment: Apart from all the other nonsense, we also try to have fun here...

Comment: Yeah, I get that, see the edit to the end of my last comment to put some fun into my critique. :P

Comment: Comments disappear in the middle of the night like dreams...some day, a new Mod may come through here and erase all comments Consider posting an answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes your comments and Chris H's comment (and finally his answer) all look to me like a good explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Don't Panic is a theme I saw several times, e.g. [Node.js on the Road: Don't Panic — The Hitchhiker's Guide to Node](https://www.joyent.com/blog/node-js-on-the-road-la-oren-golan)

Answer (score 4):

**What is the connotation of “The Hitchhiker's Guide to XYZ”?**

The exact connotations that individual authors (or their publishers) wish to convey in naming their book *“The Hitchhiker's Guide to XYZ”* is likely be a bit varied.

This is because, unlike titles of the form *“XYZ for Dummies”* which fall under the trademark of a single publisher (who curate/conform their collection to all be instructional/reference-books-for-beginners), the *“The Hitchhiker's Guide to XYZ”* template does not fall under one master trademark (and thus there is no single authority making sure everyone follows the same set of connotations).

That said, understanding some general connotations these authors/publisher's *might* be trying to convey probably requires a bit of cultural background.

---

> I guess the titles are a reference to The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.

You are correct; Douglas Adams's novel (based on the writing he had done for a BBC radio program) is the dominant reference for this snowclone/template.  I say dominant, and not original, because Adams himself jokingly based the title off the then-quite-popular travel-guide *“Hitch-hiker's Guide to Europe”* (as DJClayworth notes in more detail in his answer).  Even more confusingly, Adams's book (which is essentially a fictional narrative following the character Arthur Dent) often makes reference to an in-universe book by the same name (which is a bonafide travel-guide).

Adams's books went on to sell quite well to the general public; but the science-fiction settings and quirky, sometimes irreverent, often ironic, humor ended up cementing the book(s) as a staple in the literary canon of modern 'nerd culture'.  (Which is why copycat titles so often appear in texts about Computer Programming and nearby STEM fields.)

---

So, what general connotations *might* these authors/publisher's be trying to convey?

Some might be using the 'nerdy reference' simply to sell more copies of their tech-oriented reference book by having a title that is memorable/hip/catchy to their STEM-oriented audience (no matter what writing style they use in the text).  Others might use the reference as an indicator that their writing is "more casual than a textbook" in a similar way that *“XYZ for Dummies”* benefit from their title.  Others still might be using the reference as an indicator that the author is going to make every attempt to be humorously as quirky, irreverent, and ironic as Adams was in his tome.

In general, though, it's probably safe to assume a typical instructional/reference-book somewhere in the ballpark of *“XYZ for Dummies”* to *“(O'Reilly Media) XYZ”* with a somewhat casual style.*

* Do read at least a few pages before purchase to get a feel for the author's tone/style; comedy writing (or lack thereof) in one's personal reference library is likely to be a bit polarizing.

---

As an aside: the movie version was quite bizarre (presumably by design).  The book features a lot of wordplay, which - in addition to being very language-specific - can also be very hard to translate to film even for English-text to English-film (which I believe the film-producers tried to replicate by making the film even quirkier).  Furthermore, condensing an entire book to a single film can be difficult in terms of time... and meant that a large amount of expository material was omitted entirely to eliminate some plotlines while other exposition was expanded to clarify main plotlines for the video audience.

Google seems to indicate that there are a number of Chinese translations of the book - though I have no clue how well any of these might convey the humor properly; my best guess would be that a Hong Kong translator would likely best understand the dry British humor that is so often present.

Comment: Thanks for the long/detailed answer. I have a small question, you said "a typical instructional/reference-book somewhere in the ballpark of “XYZ for Dummies” but I get the feeling that reference-book somewhere in the ballpark of "XYZ, the definitive guide"

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 Sure! Your results may vary depending on the particular subject/book encountered.  But, the "XYZ, the Definitive Guide" template you propose seems to fall pretty near the "O'Reilly" end of he spectrum I proposed - at least if you take "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" (O'Reilly) and "Spark: The Definitive Guide" (O'Reilly) as examples.

Comment: 'The exact connotations that individual authors (or their publishers) wish to convey' or a paraphrase should preface every answer here (or better, of the question itself). +1. Connotations are often at least as much a function of the individual reader etc as of the wording.

Comment: You seem to imply that the novel is somehow the authoritative version but I believe Adams was actually happier that the radio series, novel and tv adaptation each varied somewhat from each other. I know he was also consulted on the film.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are probably quite correct of Adams's feelings on the multiple versions; my answer was mostly forwarding the primacy of the novel as compared to the 2005 movie (at least in so far as being *formative* of mainstream 'nerd culture').  I do not have a good feeling for how popular the radio series is/was in comparison to the books other than anecdotal experience that the books seem to be more well known than the US - though I could see how being broadcast free on the BBC could likely make the situation reversed in the UK.

Comment: @IMSoP Good catch on the trademark/copyright distinction.  Thank you.